# Apollo Inline fragment doesn't return data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm using Appolo and React Native to query some data. I need to get the `isRestriced` field from the response by using inline fragments. For every query, I only get `userId` without the `isRestricted` field.

I tried various things but couldn't figure out what's causing the issue. Not sure if the problem is with the inline fragment, but this code works in React, but in React-Native, I can't get any data except the `userId`.

Query:

```
export const GET_USER = gql`
  query getUser {
    loggedInUser {
      userId
      ... on MainOrganization {
        isUploadEnabled
        organization {
          isRestricted
        }
      }
    }
`;`
```

Response

```
userId: "123-456-789-123-42ade233"
__typename: "User"
```

package.json

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.3.12",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"graphql": "^15.5.0",
"graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having same issue

Answer (score 2):

Did you define a possibleTypes option in your initialization for the InMemoryCache?

see: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments#using-fragments-with-unions-and-interfaces

It could be that your client is not able to match the fragments. There are some libraries for fragment-matching out there. (f.e. https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/)

Comment: Following a major version update, I encountered the problem described above and this answer was the solution! Thank you!